# Handling playlist with youtube-sr gone wrong

Tags: node.js, youtube, discord.js

Okay, so I need to handle a youtube playlist link because I need the video id for each of the videos. But as always something goes terribly wrong, the built-in function called getPlaylist is trying to parse the playlist details to JSON, but it's filtering code isn't that right and it tries to parse this
[image]

I only want the JSON object that is colored blue, not the gibberish in red. How can I do it?

```
 static getPlaylist(html, limit = 100) {
        if (!limit || typeof limit !== "number") limit = 100;
        if (limit <= 0) limit = 100;
        const videos = [];
        let parsed;
        let playlistDetails;
        try {
            const rawJSON = `${html.split("{\"playlistVideoListRenderer\":{\"contents\":")[1].split("}],\"playlistId\"")[0]}}]`;
            parsed = JSON.parse(rawJSON);
            let log = html.split("{\"playlistSidebarRenderer\":")[1].split("\n")[0].slice(0, -3)
            console.log(log);
            // This is the part where it crashes because it tries to convert the JSON and the gibberish 
            playlistDetails = JSON.parse(html.split("{\"playlistSidebarRenderer\":")[1].split("\n")[0].slice(0, -3)).items;
        } catch (e) {
            return null;
        }
```

These are a few lines of code that I need to work, how can I filter out the gibberish?

Comment: Just take the first several characters of the gibberish in red, and put those characters in a `split()`. Because you want the content that comes before the gibberish, you would do `split("first several chars of gibberish here")[0]`. So something like: `html.split("{\"playlistSidebarRenderer\":")[1].split("\n")[0].slice(0, -3).split("}};</script><link rel")[0]`. Of course, you would need to fork `youtube-sr` and edit this code in order to do so, and the characters I chose in this example may not work properly so you need to choose whatever works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working thanks to @Cannicide. [image]

I just added a split with the starting data of the gibberish

```
playlistDetails = JSON.parse(html.split("{\"playlistSidebarRenderer\":")[1].split("\n")[0].slice(0, -3).split("}};</script><link rel=\"alternate\" media=\"handheld\" href=\"https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=")[0]).items;
```